# PyQt5 Selection Index

Tags: python, function, indexing, pyqt5

I have this code in PyQt5
That Connected to certain Database.
i just need when i select a row in program UI ,
that give me that index of the row and the column .
Like the selected Cell in the Picture below , i just want to know its column and row index. please put it in certain function like Refresh . Thank You

```
    import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlQueryModel, QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sqlite3 as lite

##############
i = 1
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
Own = QMainWindow()
Own.resize(600, 600)
##############
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("projectDB.db")
db.open()
####

projectModel = QSqlQueryModel()
projectModel.setQuery("select * from Contacts", db)
####
projectView = QTableView(Own)
projectView.resize(450, 450)
projectView.move(20, 50)
projectView.setModel(projectModel)


#########################
def New():
    New_N_Dialog = QDialog(Own)
    New_N_Dialog.setWindowTitle("New")
    New_N_Dialog.resize(700, 700)
    ##############
    Name_label = QLabel("Name : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Name_label.resize(300, 20)
    Name_label.move(20, 20)
    ########
    Name_Entry = QLineEdit(New_N_Dialog)
    Name_Entry.resize(300, 20)
    Name_Entry.move(20, 50)
    #############
    Mob_label = QLabel("Mobile : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Mob_label.resize(300, 20)
    Mob_label.move(20, 90)
    ########
    Mob_Entry = QLineEdit(New_N_Dialog)
    Mob_Entry.resize(300, 20)
    Mob_Entry.move(20, 120)
    #################
    Date_Label = QLabel("Date : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Date_Label.resize(300, 20)
    Date_Label.move(20, 150)
    #########
    Date_Entry = QCalendarWidget(New_N_Dialog)
    Date_Entry.resize(300, 200)
    Date_Entry.move(20, 180)

    ################
    Address_Label = QLabel("Address : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Address_Label.resize(300, 20)
    Address_Label.move(20, 400)
    ########
    Address_Entry = QLineEdit(New_N_Dialog)
    Address_Entry.resize(300, 20)
    Address_Entry.move(20, 430)
    ###############
    Email_Label = QLabel("Email : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Email_Label.resize(300, 20)
    Email_Label.move(20, 460)
    #######
    Email_Entry = QLineEdit(New_N_Dialog)
    Email_Entry.resize(300, 20)
    Email_Entry.move(20, 490)
    ################
    Group_Label = QLabel("Group : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Group_Label.resize(300, 20)
    Group_Label.move(20, 520)
    ######
    Group_Combo = QComboBox(New_N_Dialog)
    Group_Combo.resize(300, 20)
    Group_Combo.move(20, 550)
    ###############
    Con = lite.connect("projectDB.db")
    Cur = Con.cursor()
    Query = "select groupName from Groups"
    Cur.execute(Query)
    data = Cur.fetchall()
    for x in range(len(data)):
        Group_Combo.addItems(data[x])
    ########################## NOTES #####################
    Notes_Label = QLabel("Notes : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Notes_Label.resize(300, 20)
    Notes_Label.move(350, 20)
    #################
    Notes_Ares = QLineEdit(New_N_Dialog)
    Notes_Ares.resize(300, 520)
    Notes_Ares.move(350, 50)
    ####### Buttons #############
    Ok_But = QPushButton("OK", New_N_Dialog)
    Ok_But.resize(90, 30)
    Ok_But.move(550, 600)

    def Ok_Pressed():
        Name_To_DB = Name_Entry.text()
        Mob_To_DB = Mob_Entry.text()
        Add_To_DB = Address_Entry.text()
        Em_To_DB = Email_Entry.text()
        Note_To_DB = Notes_Ares.text()

        ###### Reformating #########

        Not_Modified = Date_Entry.selectedDate().toString()
        Not_Modified1 = "%s" % Not_Modified
        Date_list = Not_Modified1.split(" ")
        del (Date_list[0])
        Final = '-'.join(Date_list)
        # #########Group ComboBox Selecting ##########
        #
        Combo_Value = Group_Combo.currentIndex() + 1
        ######
        print(Name_To_DB)
        print(Mob_To_DB)
        print(Add_To_DB)
        print(Em_To_DB)
        print(Note_To_DB)
        print(Combo_Value)
        print(Final)
        projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(fullname) values (%s)" % Name_To_DB, db)
        projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(mobile) values(%s)" % Mob_To_DB, db)  ##Done
        projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(address) values(%s)" % Add_To_DB, db)
        projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(email) values(%s)" % Em_To_DB, db)
        projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(notes) values(%s)" % Note_To_DB, db)
        projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(groupID) values(%s)" % Combo_Value, db)  ##Done
        projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(bdate) values(%s)" % Final, db)

    Ok_But.clicked.connect(Ok_Pressed)
    ########
    Can_But = QPushButton("Cancal", New_N_Dialog)
    Can_But.resize(90, 30)
    Can_But.move(440, 600)

    def close_2():
        New_N_Dialog.close()

    Can_But.clicked.connect(close_2)
    ###############
    New_N_Dialog.show()


def New_Group():
    New_Dialog = QDialog(Own)
    New_Dialog.setWindowTitle("New Group")
    ###############
    New_Dialog.resize(200, 200)
    Label_1 = QLabel("Group ID : ", New_Dialog)
    Label_1.resize(90, 20)
    Label_1.move(25, 10)
    ####################
    Group_ID = QLineEdit(New_Dialog)
    Group_ID.resize(150, 20)
    Group_ID.move(25, 40)
    print(Group_ID.text())
    ##############
    Label_2 = QLabel("Group Name : ", New_Dialog)
    Label_2.resize(150, 20)
    Label_2.move(25, 80)
    ################
    Group_Name = QLineEdit(New_Dialog)
    Group_Name.resize(150, 20)
    Group_Name.move(25, 120)
    ################
    Ok_But = QPushButton("OK", New_Dialog)
    Ok_But.resize(50, 20)
    Ok_But.move(125, 150)

    def Adding():
        G_ID = Group_ID.text()
        projectModel.setQuery("insert into Groups(groupID) values(%s)" % G_ID, db)
        print(Group_Name.text())
        G_Name = Group_Name.text()
        projectModel.setQuery("insert into Groups(groupName) values(%s)" % G_Name, db)

    Ok_But.clicked.connect(Adding)
    ################
    Cancal_But = QPushButton("Cancal", New_Dialog)
    Cancal_But.resize(50, 20)
    Cancal_But.move(25, 150)
    New_Dialog.show()

    def close():
        New_Dialog.close()

    Cancal_But.clicked.connect(close)


def Edit():
    New_N_Dialog = QDialog(Own)
    New_N_Dialog.setWindowTitle("New")
    New_N_Dialog.resize(700, 700)
    ##############
    Name_label = QLabel("Name : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Name_label.resize(300, 20)
    Name_label.move(20, 20)
    ########
    Name_Entry = QLineEdit(New_N_Dialog)
    Name_Entry.resize(300, 20)
    Name_Entry.move(20, 50)
    #############
    Mob_label = QLabel("Mobile : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Mob_label.resize(300, 20)
    Mob_label.move(20, 90)
    ########
    Mob_Entry = QLineEdit(New_N_Dialog)
    Mob_Entry.resize(300, 20)
    Mob_Entry.move(20, 120)
    #################
    Date_Label = QLabel("Date : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Date_Label.resize(300, 20)
    Date_Label.move(20, 150)
    #########
    Date_Entry = QCalendarWidget(New_N_Dialog)
    Date_Entry.resize(300, 200)
    Date_Entry.move(20, 180)

    ################
    Address_Label = QLabel("Address : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Address_Label.resize(300, 20)
    Address_Label.move(20, 400)
    ########
    Address_Entry = QLineEdit(New_N_Dialog)
    Address_Entry.resize(300, 20)
    Address_Entry.move(20, 430)
    ###############
    Email_Label = QLabel("Email : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Email_Label.resize(300, 20)
    Email_Label.move(20, 460)
    #######
    Email_Entry = QLineEdit(New_N_Dialog)
    Email_Entry.resize(300, 20)
    Email_Entry.move(20, 490)
    ################
    Group_Label = QLabel("Group : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Group_Label.resize(300, 20)
    Group_Label.move(20, 520)
    ######
    Group_Combo = QComboBox(New_N_Dialog)
    Group_Combo.resize(300, 20)
    Group_Combo.move(20, 550)
    ###############
    Con = lite.connect("projectDB.db")
    Cur = Con.cursor()
    Query = "select groupName from Groups"
    Cur.execute(Query)
    data = Cur.fetchall()
    for x in range(len(data)):
        Group_Combo.addItems(data[x])
    ########################## NOTES #####################
    Notes_Label = QLabel("Notes : ", New_N_Dialog)
    Notes_Label.resize(300, 20)
    Notes_Label.move(350, 20)
    #################
    Notes_Ares = QLineEdit(New_N_Dialog)
    Notes_Ares.resize(300, 520)
    Notes_Ares.move(350, 50)
    ####### Buttons #############
    Ok_But = QPushButton("OK", New_N_Dialog)
    Ok_But.resize(90, 30)
    Ok_But.move(550, 600)

    def Ok_Pressed():
        Name_To_DB = Name_Entry.text()
        Mob_To_DB = Mob_Entry.text()
        Add_To_DB = Address_Entry.text()
        Em_To_DB = Email_Entry.text()
        Note_To_DB = Notes_Ares.text()

        ###### Reformating #########

        Not_Modified = Date_Entry.selectedDate().toString()
        Not_Modified1 = "%s" % Not_Modified
        Date_list = Not_Modified1.split(" ")
        del (Date_list[0])
        Final = '-'.join(Date_list)
        # #########Group ComboBox Selecting ##########
        #
        Combo_Value = Group_Combo.currentIndex() + 1
        ######
        print(Name_To_DB)
        print(Mob_To_DB)
        print(Add_To_DB)
        print(Em_To_DB)
        print(Note_To_DB)
        print(Combo_Value)
        print(Final)
        projectModel.setQuery('''update Contacts
                                set fullname = "%s"
                                where ''' % Name_To_DB, db)
        # projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(mobile) values(%s)" % Mob_To_DB, db)  ##Done
        # projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(address) values(%s)" % Add_To_DB, db)
        # projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(email) values(%s)" % Em_To_DB, db)
        # projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(notes) values(%s)" % Note_To_DB, db)
        # projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(groupID) values(%s)" % Combo_Value, db)  ##Done
        # projectModel.setQuery("insert into Contacts(bdate) values(%s)" % Final, db)

    Ok_But.clicked.connect(Ok_Pressed)
    ########
    Can_But = QPushButton("Cancal", New_N_Dialog)
    Can_But.resize(90, 30)
    Can_But.move(440, 600)

    def close_2():
        New_N_Dialog.close()

    Can_But.clicked.connect(close_2)
    ###############
    New_N_Dialog.show()


def Remove():
    print("fFFFFK")


def Refresh():
    ss = QListView()
    af = QModelIndex()
    print(af)
def fk():
    print("asdjashd")


######################
def First():
    projectModel.setQuery("select * FROM Contacts WHERE  contactID = 1", db)


def Prev():
    global i
    i = i - 1
    projectModel.setQuery("select * FROM Contacts WHERE  contactID = '%d'-1" % (i), db)


def Next():
    global i
    i = i + 1
    projectModel.setQuery("select * FROM Contacts WHERE  contactID = '%d'+1" % (i), db)


def Last():
    projectModel.setQuery("select * FROM Contacts WHERE  contactID = 100", db)


#######################
def Quit():
    sys.exit()


########################
def Reset_Table():
    projectModel.setQuery("SELECT * FROM Contacts", db)


New_But = QPushButton("New", Own)
New_But.move(490, 50)
New_But.resize(90, 30)
New_But.clicked.connect(New)
###################
New_Group_But = QPushButton("New Group", Own)
New_Group_But.move(490, 90)
New_Group_But.resize(90, 30)
New_Group_But.clicked.connect(New_Group)
################
Edit_But = QPushButton("Edit", Own)
Edit_But.move(490, 130)
Edit_But.resize(90, 30)
Edit_But.clicked.connect(Edit)
#############
Remove_But = QPushButton("Remove", Own)
Remove_But.move(490, 170)
Remove_But.resize(90, 30)
Remove_But.clicked.connect(Remove)
##############
Refresh_But = QPushButton("Refresh", Own)
Refresh_But.move(490, 210)
Refresh_But.resize(90, 30)
Refresh_But.clicked.connect(Refresh)
#########################
First_But = QPushButton("First", Own)
First_But.move(20, 520)
First_But.resize(90, 30)
First_But.clicked.connect(First)
################
Prev_But = QPushButton("Previous", Own)
Prev_But.move(120, 520)
Prev_But.resize(90, 30)
Prev_But.clicked.connect(Prev)
####################3
Next_But = QPushButton("Next", Own)
Next_But.move(220, 520)
Next_But.resize(90, 30)
Next_But.clicked.connect(Next)
#################
Last_But = QPushButton("Last", Own)
Last_But.move(320, 520)
Last_But.resize(90, 30)
Last_But.clicked.connect(Last)
##########   Quit ############
Quit_But = QPushButton("Quit", Own)
Quit_But.move(490, 420)
Quit_But.resize(90, 30)
Quit_But.clicked.connect(Quit)
######################
For_R = Own.menuBar()
Reset = For_R.addMenu('&Options')

Reset_Opt = QAction(QIcon('exit_icon.png'), 'Reset', Own)
Reset_Opt.setShortcut('Ctrl+R')
Reset_Opt.triggered.connect(Reset_Table)
Reset.addAction(Reset_Opt)
###############

########




#############
Own.show()
app.exec_()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV6cX.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK I have checked it for you and it goes like this:

```
tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
tableWidget.clicked.connect(show_row)

def show_row():    
    print(listWidget.currentRow())
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13857681)

Comment: I changed my answer. I think this has to be what you are looking for